# Use lightweight Bzr checkout from Emacs offline

Tags: version-control, emacs, offline, bazaar

I have lightweight checkout of my Bazaar repository on a workstation and edit files in these folders with Emacs. The server is down due to a power failure at the moment. I can, of course, edit the files locally in any editor. However, when fetching them in Emacs, Emacs tries to connect to the server via vc-bzr. Is there a way to put Emacs into "version control offline mode" to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Emacs but the traditional way to work offline with bzr is to use a heavy checkout or branch. When you're online again, you can try using the command `bzr reconfigure --checkout` to change your lightweight checkout into a heavy checkout.

A heavy checkout is a branch with local history which commits to the remote location first (like a lightweight checkout) and only when that succeeds does it commit locally as well.

Comment: I executed that `bzr` command from within the lightweight checkout folder, but bzr returned half a screen full of error messages. I created a checkout by simply running `bzr checkout ...` instead of trying to convert the lightweight one. I am the only user of the bzr repository on a server, but I access it from various different locations and so I use it to keep the files in sync.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove Bzr from vc-handled-backends.  But it might be considered a bug in Emacs (at least, there's code in vc-bzr.el to try and let vc-bzr find the file's status without running bzr) or maybe in Bazaar (depending on what Bzr command Emacs runs).